# Why foreman requires package foreman-mysql2-1.7.4-1.el6.noarch

Tags: mysql, theforeman

Why does it requires to install it's mysql package when I already have mysql installed, I am sorry If I sound stupid but this is my learning point.

Comment: FYI, it's a 12K "noarch" package that only contains what looks to me as a Ruby script. I don't have a Linux box to test and I can't speak Ruby but it's clearly not the MySQL Server as you're assuming.

Answer (score 0):

foreman-mysql would be the "foreman" side client code. My particular server doesn't have it, but it does have "foreman-postgresql" for example. This is not a "server" package, but since TheForeman works with multiple databases, it will require whatever client side code you need to support your preferred database server.

Tommy